# Can't Focus or Select TextBox that is part of a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, textbox

I am trying to create a scheduling application for office employees. All the information about Time In and Time Out is going to filled using the interface i am trying to build. Which brings us the the problem in hand.
 I have a DataTemplate which I am using as part of Reuseable ContentControl. I create a list of those control and add them to a StackPanel. At then end I put that stack panel into another stack panel.My problem is i can not focus or select the text boxes that are three way deep. Sometime i can select the very first TextBox of the first contentcontrol and then i can TAB to the next TextBox. But I can not directly select that second or any TextBox after the first TextBox. Even first text box feels like half of it is blocked because i have to click on left side of its center to be able to select it.

I tried to add content control directly into RootLayout and it works. I also tried to remove the second layer stack panel by adding ContentControl directly into first stackpanel (the one in my main window) it works (I think) as well.

Any thoughts? if you guys need more info or further detail into code please let me know.

Here is the DataTemplate:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="scheach">
    <Grid Width="94" Background="#FF575A5E" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.489*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.511*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.514*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.486*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Margin="3,2,2.299,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ATimeIn}" FontSize="13.333" BorderBrush="#FF1A2FE0" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0.701,2,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ATimeOut}" FontSize="13.333" BorderBrush="#FF1A2FE0" Width="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Margin="3,2.053,2.299,2.204" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0.701,2.053,1.983,2.204" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is the code to create Content Control:

```
public ContentControl GetEachInAndOut(EachSch sch,DateTime date)
    {
        ContentControl cont = new ContentControl();
        cont.DataContext = sch;
        cont.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)win.FindResource("scheach");
        return cont;
    }
```

Code to add this content control to stackpanel:

```
 //function called for each user
  public StackPanel GetWeek(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
        stack.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        stack.Width = win.Width - 30;
        stack.Margin = new Thickness(2);

        while (true)
        {
            EachSch each = new EachSch();
            stack.Children.Add(GetEachInAndOut(each, temp));
            temp = temp.AddDays(1);
            if (temp == end.AddDays(1))
                break;

        }

        return stack;        
    }
  }
```

Final Code in the main window:

```
this.stackPanel1.Children.Add(master.GetWeek(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(6)));
```

Above function is called on each user and the end i have 1+ stack panels; I add these to another stack panel that is being displayed in my window.

Update 4/22/2012: Still no luck.
I tried to create  multiple ItemsControl rather then ContentControls inside a stackpanel. I added that ItemsControl to my wrappanel in my window. Now i can click on the first two items of each listbox but all the other one are still non clickable and uneditable.

Updated 4/22/2012 6:12PM: Plan Q;
I am trying to solve my problem using the following template. Seem to fullfill my objective and I can change and edit textboxes but the problem I orinally encountered still remains. Regarding the issue i changed the `ContentControl` to `UserControl` but no luck. I finally created a usercontrol inside Windows.Forms application and Imported into WPF using WindowsFormHost. It works but..nay...I do not wanna go that route.

```
<ListBox Height="271" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,47,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="814" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Barcode}" />
                        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource scheach}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource paneltemp}" ItemsSource="{Binding Days}">
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```